# ipython extract an element from one tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to extract the first element and second element from a tuple. For example, I have a tuple, A:
`A`

> (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (2,2) (2,3) (3,3)

I know if I want to extract the first tuple, I can do

```
A[0]
```

I'll get:

> (1,1)

But if I wanted to get the first element... I tried to do

```
A[0].0
```

But that doesn't seem to work. 
Any suggestions of how to extract the first element of a single tuple? Not of all tuples.

Comment: `A[0][0]` though this is prob a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that your tuple is defined correctly! The one showed in the example is not a qualified value.

Herewith the example:

```
>>> a = ((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3))
>>> a[0]
(1, 1)
>>> a[0][0]
1
>>>
```

Hope it helps!!